# Escaping brackets in filename. Shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I have many files with pattern name:

```
N.apple(d).log
```

e.g. `001.apple(d).log`, `002.apple(d).log`, etc.

The problem is when I am trying to do something with the files in a bash script, there is always an error 'No such file or directory' even with escaped brackets:

```
for i in $(ls my_folder); do file=$(echo $i | sed 's/(/\\(/g' | sed 's/)/\\)/g') ; head -1 my_folder/$file; done
```

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes. Also, don't use ls when the shell can expand the wildcards just fine already.

```
for i in my_folder/*; do head -1 "$i"; done
```

Comment: The loop can go, too: `head -1 my_folder/*`.

Comment: While that is also true, I was assuming that there was more to the loop, and the head was simply an example. But, maybe that was an optimistic assumption :)